# Does it make geometric sense to say that open rectangles and open balls generate the same open sets

Tags: general-topology, geometry, intuition

I have always been bothered by when people say:

The open ball (i.e. $L_2$ ball) and the open rectangle (i.e. $L_\infty$ ball) generates the same open sets (topology) on $\mathbb{R}^2$

The proof is something of the sort you can always put a square inside a ball and a ball inside of a square...

But geometrically does it make sense?

[image]

I find it hard to believe that given a random "blob" in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is generated by through countable union of open balls or open rectangles. I mean rectangles have corners don't they...?

How is it geometrically intuitive that every open set is generated by open balls or open rectangles?

Comment: You know how you can make a picture of a circle using a rectangular array of pixels?

Comment: Its not just a random blob, its a random **open** blob. You can fit a circle inside a square and a square inside a rectangle. It is related to the fact that the rationals are dense in the reals.

Comment: @Rahul Yes but the circle doesn't generate the rectangle, nor the other way around, otherwise we would square the circle?

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows What you just said makes no sense. There is no connection at all with unions of circles forming a square and squaring the circle. Anyhow, *yes* a square without its boundary is a countable Union of open circles.

Comment: "I mean rectangles have corners don't they..."? **No**, *open* rectangles don't have corners. There is no *boundary* to an open rectangle: the "edges" are deleted.

Comment: (Also, circles and rectangles have nothing to do with it: shape is a geometrical notion, not a topological one. The same open sets are generated by open ellipses, open diamonds, open nonagons...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Infinite Unions** is the key to understand this. 
Intuitively, the situation is described in the following figure:
[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the graphics it explains a lot but it still seems like we are taking things a little bit on faith that all those white gaps will all be covered by circle such that no circle will be out of the set, and all the white spaces will be covered down to a point...It seems no matter how you fill it you will eventually have some white spaces not fully covered by a ball

Comment: No if you use infinite unions! Beware: infinite is the key word! You can always cover any empty space either with a square or a rectangle, since both of them can be made arbitrarily small and you can always use an infinite number of them.

Comment: NOTE: it is critical that everything here is *open*. No "edge" points are included, so you can always fit an open rectangle around an interior point of an open disc, and you can always fit an open disc around an interior point of an open rectangle. That shows the topologies are the same.

Comment: Infinite unions really has nothing to do with the fact that open circles and open rectangles generate the same topology. All you need is that every point of an open circle sits inside an open rectangle lying entirely in the circle, and vice versa. No infinity required.

Comment: @ symplectomorphic: you certainly cannot do this without infinity.

Answer (score 1):

> but geometrically does it make sense?

The only geometric thing to consider is that you can inscribe or circumscribe a circle with a square, and that all makes complete sense.

From there it is completely clear how one would express an open set (defined by circles) as a union of open squares: capture each point inside the set with an open circle, then shrink each one to an open square. The union of all those squares is inside the open set, and every point of the open set is contained in one.

The same argument works in the other direction. Shape is not all that important For open sets. After all, you don't even have a metric a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that topoloy can be though of as the study of "stretching without tearing" and then it is common to identify two spaces when one can be deformed into the other (ie homeomorphism). Anyhow, suppose you've got a circle made of super strecthy material, then you can stretch it, without tearing, into a rectangle; and vice versa. Now if you've got an open set which is just the Union of a bunch of open circles and you know how to deform the circles into rectangles, then that open set is also a union of a bunch of open rectangles. :-) hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is what if I took a rectangle and placed the corner on the boundary of the circle. I could do this an infinite amount of times and eventually work my way all around the circle. The reason I can do this is because the circles and rectangles are both open.